# Device still has the old apk

Tags: android, apk

I installed my app apk into my device and now when ever I try to install new apk, somehow the old apk is installed again. I deleted the apk file from memory card and unistalled the app and cleared data and cache, but somehow some of the old apk data is saved in memory card that I can not clear and is appearing every time I install new apk.  So when I go in and delete all the old files and open the new one it is still prompting me that it will save user data which means some where it is still storing something.

I am really confused about this problem, please help me finding solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411871/android-studio-wont-install-a-new-apk-old-one-wont-go-away-on-phone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It could be due to a virus.

Try the following options:
1) Uninstall app
2) Format SD card
3) Restore phone to original settings
4) Install antivirus app 
5) Restart phone

This should surely remove the app.

On your dev machine, delete any .apk files generated in .bin directory. In Eclipse, make sure you do a Project -> Clean

Comment: I don't see how you would be able to guess that the user needs AV on his phone from the above description.

Comment: @wojci : User describes that he deletes the apk and it still exists. That behavior is impossible to reproduce unless there was a virus preventing the file deletion.

Comment: @Sagar, Formatting the SD card will require reinstalling all apps , I am using Ormlite in my app , is orm lite a good option to be used for data ? i mean may be orm lite is creating this problem?

Comment: @MobileDevFast Ormlite could be the problem too. I haven't really used it but seems like you should try that before formatting the SD card. BTW, I don't believe you'd require to re-install all the apps - you just login using your Google Play account and all of your apps with that account should get synched.

Comment: So what should i use instead of ORMLite? And can u please tell me why ORMLite is not a good option to be used for database?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem stems from some issues with Eclipse. Go to `Project > clean` on the top bar and try again. This is a guess though, but let me know if its not the issue.

Comment: Hi Andy , the problem is not with apk, it is running perfect on emulator , but when i install this apk on device some how old apk appears there .