# Android Studio won't install a new APK - old one won't go away on phone

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

My app won't update. It builds and runs but it's some old version and the changes I've made aren't counted. If I make a Toast for example, it won't show. If I delete an existing one, it will still show.

I've tried the following already:

- Updating Android Studio and updates in the SDK manager
- uninstalling the app off my phone and reinstalling
- cleaning
- make sure "Gradle-aware Make" is in run configurations
- File - invalidate caches
- make sure "Skip installation" is unticked.
- delete the build folder of the project and rebuilt
- adb shell pm clear com.packagename.app - "Success" but not fixed
- adb shell uninstall com.packagename.app - "Success" but not fixed
- Increase versionCode and versionName in build.gradle
- Change build variant
- Making a new project and copying the files
- [Android Studio is installing old apk on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831082/android-studio-is-installing-old-apk-on-device)

I've tried doing it on another phone and it's stuck on an older version on that one too.

Comment: 1) you could try and change version in the Manifest. 2) longer way around, make new project, move all stuff over (kinda works for smaller projects). Make sure different App name...

Comment: @Flummox It's not a small project and what do I do when it happens again, make a new project again and move all the stuff over again etc. etc. etc.?

Comment: I don't like to have to create a whole new project, but I do not know a better way around then that...

Comment: Where is the old APK even coming from? I deleted it from the phone and deleted the build folder but it keeps coming back!

Comment: Setting the Build variant?

Comment: @Flummox What about setting the build variant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112807/discussion-between-flummox-and-questioner).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+studio+not+updating+apk
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831082/android-studio-is-installing-old-apk-on-device

Comment: @Flummox That question is where I got some of the things I tried and showed in my question. For example, the "Gradle aware make" part worked for the OP of that question but didn't for me.

Comment: I ended up making a new project and copying the source folders to the new project and trying again. Even that didn't work.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and I tried all of the above. I've also tried to build a second app and I still get an old APK of the first!!! Have you found a way to fix it? Only help I can provide is that even when I go for a clean build  I get the following in the gradle log:

    `:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE`
     `:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE`
     `:app:checkDebugManifest`
     `:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE`

Seems strange to me but I'm unsure of it has anything to do with it...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with AndroidStudio Canary 2020.3.1 Canary 2.

In my case it helped to check Run/Debug Configurations/Always install with package manager.

(I might have missed some simple reason for this behaviour, though.)

Answer (score 1):

It's due to a bug in Android Studio because of Deploy optimizations on Android 11.

Temporary fix is to disable optimizations by following the below:
In toolbar > Run > Edit Configurations... > General Tab > Check: Always install with package manager

Answer (score 0):

I would comment this, but I can't yet, so... I would try to delete the .apk from "Project\app\build\outputs\apk" folder. Or at least check it's modification date.

Comment: I forgot to add in the original question that I deleted the whole build folder.

Comment: Oh I see. And does Android Studio build the folders and apks there when you build your app after delete? (I guess it does).

Comment: Yes, and they are dated today

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion XX
    targetSdkVersion XX
    versionCode 1 // <-- set this one to a bigger, it is used for upgrade
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Already did that. Actually made a comment saying I did it but my internet connection dropped just at that moment.

Comment: @Questioner - did you ever get this resolved? I'm running into the same problem and have tried so many different things to fix it and nothing is working.